# Looking for Anti-XSS or Web-base html malware scan API

Tags: asp.net, .net, antixsslibrary

Any tool/API allows to scan Anti-XSS codes/scripting?  Not MS Anti-XSS scans the codes but not specify what kind of thread(s).

In other words, the API only needs to scan the codes/script and provide the level of threads.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out https://scanii.com - it's a malware/content detection API. Here's an example call (using curl):

```
$ curl -u $SCANII_CREDS -F file=@Planilha_Orcamento.vbs https://api.scanii.com/v2.1/files
{
  "id" : "2376aaaa5d0bc3642a89bef870d5f4b5",
  "checksum" : "fd7b73541571b67964fd22997a987cae5feaac4b",
  "content_length" : 2768,
  "findings" : [ "content.malicious.porcupine.malware.36555.unofficial" ],
  "creation_date" : "2017-01-18T03:46:00.808Z",
  "content_type" : "text/plain",
  "metadata" : { }
}
```

Full disclosure, scanii is my project.